# Feeding a server information from JavaScript methods in Python?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, client-server, urllib2

I'm looking to automate registering to workouts by letting Python do it at set times (e.g every wednesday at 00:00). Looking at the source code I get when I am logged in, the site has the following snippet:

```
function getBookingDetails(booking_id, activity_id, center_id, activity_date, clicked_element) {
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    dataType:"json",
    url:"//censored",
    data:{
        action:"get_booking_details",
        booking_id:booking_id,
        activity_id:activity_id,
        center_id:center_id,
        date:activity_date
    },
    success:function (data) {
        if (data.success) {
            //console.log(data);
            showBookingModal(data);
        } else if (data.error_message) {
            alert(data.error_message);
        }
    }
});
}

$(document).ready(function() {

$('.buymodalclose').click(function() {
    $('#buymodal').modal('hide');
})

$('#confirm-booking-button').click(function () {
$(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
$('#modal_form').hide();
$('#modal_loading').show();

$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    dataType:"json",
    url:"//censored",
    data:{
        action:"confirm_booking",
        center_id:$(this).data('centerid'),
        booking_id:$(this).data('bookingid'),
        activity_id:$(this).data('activityid')
    },
    success:function (data) {
        if (data.success) {
            bookingResult(data);
```

Is there any way I can feed the parameters (and possibly get them?) directly to the server? E.g by sending a `urllib request` ?

The other way I suppose would be to read the page step by step, extract the information needed and in some way send that information to the booking page?